# How to disallow overwriting cookbook version in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

If I forget to change `version` in `metadata.rb` and do `knife cookbook upload …`, I lose current version content. How can I restrict uploading exist cookbook version to Chef server?

Answer (score 1):

Use `knife cookbook upload --freeze`. This prevents uploading another version on top of it. If you use [berkshelf](https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html) this is the default, which we highly recommend (or policyfiles but those work differently such that overwriting isn’t actually possible).

Comment: I've already read about `--freeze` in https://docs.chef.io/cookbook_versions.html, but in this case everyone in our company have to use `--freeze` for every cookbook version. Is it possible to restrict overwriting existing cookbook version on Chef server side?

Comment: No, that is not available. This is one of many reasons to use berks instead of knife cookbook upload.

Comment: Is it possible to `freeze` an _existing_ version of a cookbook, without uploading anything?